# How do I echo the values of this array?

Tags: php, arrays, class, object, foreach

How to echo the contents of this array using **foreach** in php? The things I need are **Outcome,Identity** etc of Array[0] and [1]. Could someone please help?

```
stdClass Object ( [GetRealTimeRatesResult] => stdClass Object ( [Rate]
=> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Outcome] => Success [Identity] => Header [Delay] => 0.0067521 [BaseCurrency] => EUR [QuoteCurrency] => USD [Symbol] => EURUSD [Date] => 07/13/2015 [Time] => 8:07:38 AM [QuoteType] => Spot [Bid] => 1.10595 [Mid] => 1.105995 [Ask] =>
1.10604 [Spread] => 9.0E-5 [Text] => 1 European Union euro = 1.105995 United States dollars [Source] => SIX Financial Information, Buyer = "ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen", Seller = "ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen" ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Outcome] => Success [Delay] => 0 [BaseCurrency] => AUD [QuoteCurrency] => USD [Symbol] => AUDUSD [Date] => 07/13/2015 [Time] => 8:07:38 AM [QuoteType] => Spot [Bid] => 0.74166 [Mid] => 0.741705 [Ask] => 0.74175 [Spread] => 9.0E-5 [Text] => 1 Australian dollar = 0.741705 United States dollar [Source]
=> SIX Financial Information, Buyer = "ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen", Seller = "ZKB Zuercher Kantonalbank, Devisen" ) ) ) )
```

**Solved:**

```
foreach($result->GetRealTimeRatesResult->Rate as $row){
    echo $row->Outcome;
}
```

Comment: Try $object->GetRealTimeRatesResult->Rate[0]->Outcome to get the Outcome

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano: How to get it inside a foreach loop?

Comment: Got the solution: 
`foreach($result->GetRealTimeRatesResult->Rate as $row){
 echo $row->Outcome;
}`

Comment: yup. it works like that